# How to implement grep in bash scripting?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I am working on to search a string on files using grep in a directory(in for loop)

```
for file in .* *; do 
    if [[ -f "$file" && `grep -r "$pattern" "$file"` ]]; then
    path=`pwd`/"$file"
    echo "$path"
    fi
done
```

Comment: ok and are you getting error or no result etc? Take your time to present your question to get quick response.

Comment: missing a closing `fi;` and a closing `done;`, in that order.

Comment: Also what if the string occurs more than once, ie in different files?

Comment: Adding `-r` to `grep` when you only apply it to a file is unnecessary; the `-r` only has an effect when a directory is given as an argument to `grep`.  But why not let `grep` do the job?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the for loop and use something like

```
grep -l "${pattern}" ${PWD}/.* ${PWD}/*
```

or better

```
find ${PWD} -type f -exec grep -l "${pattern}" {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Use find command . To search in current folder

```
find . -exec grep "$pattern" {} \; -print'
```

To search in specific folder

```
find /home/hduser  -exec grep "$pattern" {} \; -print'
```